# Como redireccionar después de un mensaje de confirmación en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Buenas tengo esta función que es un mensaje de confirmación al darle clic en un enlace y estoy tratando de redireccionar a otra pagina cuando le dan cancelar pero no me funciona alguien me puede ayudar.

**Función JavaScript**

```
function ConfirmarCopiaEncuesta() {
    var respuesta = confirm('Esta seguro que desea copiar la encuesta?');
    if (respuesta == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
        window.location.href = "miclubapp.com/plataform/";

    }

}
```

**Enlace html**

```
<a class="green Copiar_Encuesta" href="encuestasinfinita.php?action=copiarEncuesta&id=643&IDModulo=135" onclick="return ConfirmarCopiaEncuesta()">
```

y lo que pasa es que es una grilla de datos y mas abajo hay una funcion y siempre entra en esa funcion y la redirige a otro lado

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {
                location.href = "<?php echo $script ?>.php?action=edit&id=" + id + "&IDModulo=" + "<?php echo $_GET["IDModulo"] ?>";
                return false;
            },
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Después del return sales de la función. La linea de redireccion nunca se ejecuta.

Answer (score 0):

lo mas sencillo es seria asi:

```js
    function ConfirmarCopiaEncuesta() {
        var respuesta = confirm('Esta seguro que desea copiar la encuesta?');
        if(respuesta){
          return true;
        }else{
        window.location.replace("/");
        return false;
        }

    }
```

es sencillo lo primero es tener en cuenta que el if no es necesario especificar el valor `respuesta == true` ya que eso lo podemos comparar solo con el if, seguido a eso es mejor usar el `window.location.replace("url")`.

saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es queestás haciendo el `return` antes de redireccionar. Cuando devuelves algo con `return`, esto detiene tu función, por lo que no está llegando al redirect. Primero tendrías que hacer el redirect, y luego devolver lo que necesites:

```
function ConfirmarCopiaEncuesta() {
    var respuesta = confirm('Esta seguro que desea copiar la encuesta?');
    if (respuesta == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        window.location.href = "miclubapp.com/plataform/";
        return false;
    }
}
```